# Is there a Java library for steganography?

Tags: java, steganography

By library I mean a use-ready .jar distribution.

Image [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) would suffice. Working with JPEG, PNG and BMP would be enough too.

Google yields no usable results - mostly explanations and guides, but no libraries.

Comment: @Perception - is the link you pasted supposed to clarify what steganography means? I'd rather link to wikipedia if at all. Otherwise you should post it as an answer (Neal already did) or a comment.

Answer (score 4):

1. https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~eberdahl/Projects/Paranoia/index.html
   You can download the paranoia.jar from the page.
2. http://www.vclcomponents.com/Delphi/Graphical_Controls/ImageHide-info.html
   This gives you an executable. Google for the source if you want. May be available as its free too.

Comment: The paranoia lib looks interesting, ahve to try it's "experimental" JPEG module. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Searching on Sourceforge for "java steganography" gave me 6 hits.  You could try the same on GitHub, GoogleCode and so on.

(Yea, a plain Google search doesn't have any useful hits in the first page or so.  Too many of those useless "download stuff for free" parasites ... pushing the useful links down the search result set.)

---

The problem is that if *you* can find an open source steganography library, then so can the folks you are trying to hide stuff from.  This may provide them with the clues they need to 1) figure out which library you are using and 2) defeat your scheme.

Comment: Found some projects on github that look promising. I was rather hoping for a mature solution though, ideally one that is used by someone besides it's author. But it's better than nothing.